# preserve svg properties when exporting to latex

Tags: python, svg, latex, plotly, inkscape

I don't even know where to ask this question. I have code in Python which generates data and export tables and plots with `plotly` to `svg` files. Then, with Inkscape these files are formatted to `pdf_tex` to be included in `LaTeX`. All programs are run inside Python. But when I export `svg` to `pdf_tex` and further import it in `LaTeX`, font size and text positions are not the same as the initial `svg`. Pictures below are initial `svg` and exported result in PDF. How can I preserve all those properties in my final files?

initial:
[image: exported by plotly in python]

final:
[image: exported by inkscape to latex]

Comment: Why not do the tables directly in latex? You could for example export your numbers into a .csv file and then use the `csvsimple` to create a nice looking table

Comment: Can you show the .pdf_tex file?

Comment: ... and please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Answer (score 0):

It's the font that is different. Make sure that the same font is used in all steps of the process. I think for the pdfLatex export, you need to define it in the front matter of the template file you feed in.